# Using binary flags to represent states, options, etc

Tags: c++, binary, flags

If I wanted to represent states or options or something similar using binary "flags" so that I could pass them and store them to an object like `OPTION1 | OPTION2` where `OPTION1` is 0001 and `OPTION2` is 0010, so that what gets passed is 0011, representing a mix of the options.

How would I do this in C++? I was thinking something like

```
enum Option {
    Option_1 = 0x01,
    Option_2 = 0x02,
    Option_3 = 0x04,
    //...
}

void doSomething(Option options) {
    //...
}

int main() {
    doSomething(Option_1|Option_2);
}
```

But then ideally, `doSomething` knows how to interpret the given Option.

Am I on the right track? Is there a better way?

**Update**

And wouldn't I have to define an `Option` for every possible combination, also?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common way these things are done. `doSomething` can use bitwise `and` operator to see if an option is selected:

```
if (options & Option_1){ 
  // option 1 is selected
}
```

Alternatively, you can consider using [bit fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe(VS.71).aspx):

```
struct Options {
    unsigned char Option_1 : 1;
    unsigned char Option_2 : 1;
};

Options o;
o.Option_1 = 1;
o.Option_2 = 0;
```

Comment: What are bit fields? How would I use them?

Comment: Austin: see the link I posted and the sample in my answer.

Comment: Damn, 4 years of professional C++ development, and I had NEVER even heard or read about bit fields!

Comment: Gotta be careful about bitfields, though, as outlined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

That'd be the way I'd do it. However there are many tricks you can use to make the enumeration a little more readable:

```
enum Option {
    Option1 = 1 /*<< 0*/,
    Option2 = 1 << 1,
    Option3 = 1 << 2,
    // etc.
};
```

What is more, you'll need to specify bitwise operators for your enumeration. Consider something like [ASL's `enum_ops`](http://stlab.adobe.com/group__enum__ops.html) utilities to help out with this.

Comment: I use this style as well, much less confusing and totally nifty!

Answer (score 3):

Its worth noting that the way people usually use such flags is to define the function as follows:

```
void doSomething( unsigned int options ) 
{
    //...
}
```

everything else will work exactly as you want :)

The other way is to create your own "Flags" class.  Then you have a couple of functions as follows in the class:

```
bool GetOption( Option option )
{
    return (m_Option & option) > 0;
}

void SetOption( Option option )
{
    m_Option |= option;
}

void ClearOption( Option option )
{
    m_Option &= ~option;
}
```

or even overload the operators to do exactly as you'd like e.g:

```
Flags( unsigned int options ) :
   m_Option( options )
{
}

Flags operator|( const Flags& flags )
{
    return Flags( m_Option | flags.m_Option );
}
```

and so on.

Comment: Not ideal in the spirit of data hiding, however. If your number of options later exceeds 32, you'd be forced to change your code.

Comment: True ... the version i wrote of this actually used a template parameter

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the [stl bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/). Some people would preach that you should always use those instead of C-style bitflags. However, both solutions are fine IMO.